# Curl not working and returning 400 Bad Request

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a curl request to post some data to a restful api.
That's the code I have:

```
$header = "POST HTTP/1.0 \r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/xml \r\n";
$header .= "Content-length: " . strlen($xml) . " \r\n";
$header .= "Content-transfer-encoding: text \r\n";
$header .= "Connection: close \r\n\r\n";
$header .= $xml;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    print curl_error($ch);
} else {
    curl_close($ch);
    echo 'success';
}
```

`$xml` contains the data I want to post.

Well, the problem is that when I run the script it echoes 'Success' but the post is not really done.

What could be the problem here?

Thanks.

EDIT: `var_dump($data)` returns a `400 Bad Request` is there any way to solve this?

Comment: did you ever dump the $data?

Comment: It returns 400: Bad Request

Comment: Is there any way to see the actual request so I can try to fix it?

Comment: why are you using `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` for post? you may be interested in this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to add another parameter in curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
```

where $postData it's your post data